# How can I calculate the max. allowable load for my reference voltage?

Tags: tl431

I have a 2.5V reference voltage set up like so:

[image]

I want to determine how many ohms in load this 2.5V can bear before the TL431 is unable to hold the voltage. I know that this IC requires 500uA to 1mA in order to regulate the voltage. How would I go by calculating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the IC gets 1mA for it to be **guaranteed** to work. That means that a load between 2V5 and ground must not draw more than the current through R minus 1mA, which you can easily calculate. Then convert that to a resistance. If this is a homework problem you are (probably) done.

If you are doing a worst-case design for high reliability you would also consider the tolerance and temperature coefficients of R, the maximum voltage of the TL431 and the minimum voltage of the nominal 5V supply.

If the reference is called upon to sink current (which is not as typical), then refer to the datasheet current limit and thermal properties.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It's not a homework; just that I use this reference in a bunch of different places and I need to adjust the resistance to give me (and the TL431) enough current. Thanks!